# Multivariable limit - prove $\lim_{ (x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^4 -4y^4)}{x^2-2y^2}=0.$

Tags: limits

i need help on proving that the limit below equals 0. I tried some paths and all of them equal to 0. Can we prove it using something else instead of ε-δ definition?

$\displaystyle \lim_{ (x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^4 -4y^4)}{x^2-2y^2}$

Comment: $|\sin t|\le|t|$ and $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b).$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you compute the limit with multiple variables without fail?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251884/how-do-you-compute-the-limit-with-multiple-variables-without-fail)

Comment: As an alternative, we can use that

$$ \frac{\sin(x^4 -4y^4)}{x^2-2y^2}=\frac{\sin(x^4 -4y^4)}{x^4-4y^4}\cdot \frac{x^4-4y^4}{x^2-2y^2}$$

and refer to standard limit $\frac{\sin t}t \to 1$ as $t \to 0$.